# How to add onAdClick callback in rewarded-ads? - AdMob - Android

Tags: android, admob, ads

I am trying to implement ads in my App. I go though the official documentation and implemented interstitial ads into my app. It is working fine. [As Described Here](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial)

As I also know that admob will block my admob account if any malicious user clicks on my ads again and again. So to protect that, I had setup a threshold of 3 clicks i.e. If a user try to click on my ads more than 3 times in a single day, I will not show ads for next 48 hours. So, to implement this functionality with interstitial ads I use onAdClick() callback in interstitial ads. [As shown here](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial#ad_events)

But, when I try to implement the same thing with rewarded ads, I find that their is no such callback which can help me to detect clicks on rewarded ads. [See here](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/rewarded-ads).

Can someone help me to achieve this functionality. Is there any alternative ways? Please help me to come out from this scenario. If it is not possible than what I can do to protect my admob account from malicious users?

Comment: Ankush I have updated my answer again check it once...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method 1**

There is legacy API available for the rewarded ad Check here for more information... [Rewarded Video Ads (Legacy API)](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/rewarded-video)

So how it works? Check the code below

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private RewardedVideoAd mRewardedVideoAd;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mRewardedVideoAd= MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(this);

        mRewardedVideoAd.loadAd("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917",new AdRequest.Builder().build());     // You need to pass your rewared video ad Id here...

        mRewardedVideoAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener(new RewardedVideoAdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onRewardedVideoAdOpened() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onRewardedVideoStarted() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onRewarded(RewardItem rewardItem) {
                //Reward your user here....
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Congrats you got reward", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication() {
                //User clicked on ad here write your caching code here....
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked on Ad", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int i) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onRewardedVideoCompleted() {

            }
        });



        findViewById(R.id.my_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mRewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()) {
                    mRewardedVideoAd.show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please Wait..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });


    }
}
```

**Pros** Using this method: It does your work you can get callbacks on clicking ad

**Cons** Google recommends new RewardedAPI ..(Although legacy API still works fine .... )

Why does Google recommend new RewardedAPI over Legacy?

The new rewarded API is an improvement over the legacy API because

1. it allows you to Cache multiple ads.
2. The legacy rewarded API only lets you load one ad at a time, and you can't load a second ad until the first one finishes.
3. The new rewarded API lets you cache multiple ads at the same time.
   Access the reward value at ad load time. The legacy implementation
   only provides access to the reward when it's time to grant the user
   the reward.
4. For apps that use the reward value from the AdMob UI, this improvement enables you to show the user their reward before they watch the ad. Initialize mediation partners. If you use rewarded mediation, the newly rewarded APIs support initialization of mediation adapters before the first ad load. The legacy rewarded API
   does not initialize adapters, and mediation adapters were more likely to time out on the first request of a session. Migrating from the legacy rewarded API? Make sure to update your mediation adapters to the latest version, as the adapters had to migrate as well.

**Method 2:**

Since the new Rewarded API doesn't have any callbacks for click events on the ad I recommend you to cache the total number of times the user requested for ads ... limit the number of times they can request that ads

For example: In 24 hrs they can only request 3 times

Pros: As listed above Google recommends it for certain reasons 
Cons: It doesn't solve your problem ...

Comment: Sorry to say, But onRewardedAdOpened() always called when the ad is displayed to user. It does not called on actual clicking of the ad.

Comment: It seems like google takes care for fraud clicks in new rewarded ads and that's the only reason why they had not provided any way for developers to check clicks. So, I am just thinking to keep Google to track frauds and I will focus on my main app only. I just want to know is there any risk of suspension of admob account in this approach or not?

Comment: @Ankush I found an alternative way ... for this, I will update my answer with that ... check it after 20 mins

Comment: Firstly, I checked the documentation for that too. As in the documentation says this method is called when user leaves the activity and opens any other app. So, it can be called if user presses home button, or opens an app from notifications, etc. It is not the exact solution to solve the problem. Secondly, you are right! Google is recommending us to use new Rewarded API. This is because, new API has few functions which old API doesn't have. I am also using one of its feature(Rewarded Ads Server Side Verification) so can't use old API.

Comment: Although I haven't checked clicking on notification but ..I have checked clicking home button it didn't triggered onLeftApplication

Comment: Okk But, I didn't want to use Old API due to its limitations. I want an solution for the New Rewarded Ads only.

Comment: As there is no way for now. I will use second method with limiting number of ads in a day. Thanks

Comment: Yeah ... It's better to use 2nd method only if that's the case...